# Internal working of 'ref' keyword with two objects pointing to the same address

Tags: c#, ref

Look at the code below and tell me why after calling the function UpdateContext, the variable connection2 don't have the same hashcode that variable connection1.

When I set the variable connection2 to connection1, both variables have a pointer to the same memory address. But after passing the variable connection1 by ref in the function UpdateContext that modify the pointer with the 'new' instruction, the connection1 have a new pointer address but the connection2 is still with the old address.

```
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var connectionInitializer = new ConnectionInitializer();

         connectionInitializer.Initialize();

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }

   public class Connection
   {

   }

   public class ConnectionInitializer
   {
      public void Initialize()
      {
         var connection1 = new Connection();
         var connection2 = connection1;

         Console.WriteLine("Connection 1 (Before ref): " + connection1.GetHashCode());
         Console.WriteLine("Connection 2 (Before ref): " + connection2.GetHashCode());

         this.UpdateContext(ref connection1);

         Console.WriteLine("Connection 1 (After ref): " + connection1.GetHashCode());
         Console.WriteLine("Connection 2 (After ref): " + connection2.GetHashCode());
      }

      private void UpdateContext(ref Connection connection)
      {
         connection = new Connection();
      }
   }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are passing a reference type by reference, so that is expected behavior. You point the connection1 reference to a new object in UpdateContext, but connection2 will of course still point to the old object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connection2` still references the original `Connection` object.  `connection1` has been modified to refer to a new `Connection` object.  `connection1` and `connection2` are not literally the same reference.  `connection2` is a copy of `connection1` and both of these references, for a time, referred to the same object.

These two references are not linked in any meaningful way aside from what they refer to, one is simply a copy of another.  Changing the original will not reflect upon the copy.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why I was thinking that when you set a variable to the same address to another, both shared the same address even if you change address to one or other. This is actually not a problem with 'ref' keyword but with my misunderstanding like @KirkWoll said. Putting some variables to the same address is not a task that I do a lot in my applications. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be misunderstanding what `ref` is intended to achieve.  Basically, when you pass a variable as a `ref` parameter, it allows the callee to modify the value of the (original) variable exactly as if it were local.  Given that, why would you expect overwriting the value of the variable `connection1` to also change the value assigned to `connection2`?

To put it another way, using `ref` is analogous to this code:

```
var connection1 = new Connection();
var connection2 = connection1;
connection1 = new Connection()
```

Obviously in this scenario, `connection2` should be unchanged.  The same is true for yours.

Answer (score 1):

While Kirk Woll's answer is correct, I think he misses the point a bit when he says that you misunderstand the `ref` keyword.  This misunderstanding is very common, but it is more a misunderstanding about the nature of reference types themselves.

Kirk's explanation ("using ref is analogous to this code") actually mirrors other SO questions I recall, such as "Why doesn't the following example print `Goodbye`?"

```
string a = "Hello";
string b = a;
a = "Goodbye";
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

(Sorry, couldn't find the link to the actual question.)

It's all much easier to keep track of if you remember that a reference-type variable stores a *reference to* an instance of the reference type, while a value-type variable directly stores an instance of the value type.

I find this a much better way of thinking than the usual "reference types are passed by reference; value types are passed by value."  In fact, reference-type variables (absent `ref` or `out`) are passed *by value*, but the value itself is a reference.  That's confusing.  Far less confusing: "reference-type variables hold a reference to an instance of the type".

Of course, the `ref` keyword complicates this somewhat, since a ref parameter holds a reference to a variable.  This means that a reference-type `ref` parameter stores a reference to a reference to an instance of the type.  Again, if you think of the fact that reference-type variables hold references, you can just stop at the ref parameter holding a reference to the variable.  This is far easier to reason about than "reference to a reference to a...".

Answer (score 0):

It allocates new memory and hence new hashcode when you initialise connection object

Answer (score 0):

If you speak c++, refs and outs are really just pointers and you're passing the address of the identifier passed. Compare to:

```
void foo(int** p);

int main()
{
  int* one = new int(4);
  int* two = one;

  cout << "one|two before: " << *one << "|" << *two << endl;

  foo(&one);

  cout << "one|two after: " << *one << "|" << *two << endl;

  return 0;
}

void foo(int** p)
{
  *p = new int(5);
}
```

output:

```
one|two before: 4|4
one|two after: 5|4
```

**NOTE** I could have used c++ ref passing, but under the hood, those are just pointers too.